# ifconfig on removing block

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks

I would like to remove the discount code block but have it manageable.

I know if I want to remove it I can do

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layout>
<checkout_cart_index>
<reference name="content">
<remove name="checkout.cart.coupon"/>
</reference>
</checkout_cart_index>
</layout>
```

However if I try to add `ifconfig="module/manage_settings/enable_module"` it doesnt work

I have also tried

```
<action method="unsetChild" ifconfig="module/manage_settings/enable_module">
                <name>checkout.cart.coupon</name>
            </action>
```

Could someone please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set empty template:

```
<reference name="checkout.cart.coupon">
    <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="module/manage_settings/enable_module">
         <template>somefolder/empty.phtml</template>
    </action>
</reference>
```

and create `somefolder/empty.phtml`without content.